# AppService isn't able to deploy my large site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

For some unknown reason, deploying to Azure App Service using Azure Devops isn't working

When I go use Kudu to look into `D:\home\site\wwwroot`, I see the file `FAILED TO DOWNLOAD ZIP FILE.txt`.

The file has the following text:

`Run From Package Initialization failed. Unsupported Zip format or corrupted zip file.`

When look into `D:\home\data\SitePackages`, I can see my builds that are fairly large:

[image]

When I download these packages, I can unzip them and see my published files.

What's going? Why does App Service think the zip file is corrupted? I'm able to deploy a different and smaller web app to the same app service just fine.

This [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4734) seems somewhat related.

Comment: In this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements-discussions/issues/32#issuecomment-366002631),davidebbo said Free/Shared/Consumption really large zips could hit the limit.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeChen - totally overlooked that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this may work, could you try re downloading the publish profile from Azure. And publish straight from visual studio. And when you click publish, try to import the publish profile.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I found the solution and it has nothing to do with how large the site is. The problem lies somewhere in this web.config but I can't explain exactly what. When I delete this file, the error mysteriously goes away.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
      <environmentVariables />
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```